# Kali Linux Monitor mode usb network adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

How to setup network adapter in monitor mode in Kali Linux?

its Alfa AWUS036H If I type sudo airmon-ng then its empty. No interfaces.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To enable promiscuous (monitor) mode on a network card, you need to follow these steps:

Edit Network Adapter.

Next to Promiscuous mode, select Enabled.

The network adapter is now set for promiscuous mode.

Can you find this setting on your USB card?  It may not support monitor mode (promiscuous mode).  It does not appear to above.

If your Kali Machine is a virtual machine, you need to go to the Virtual App Host, and to the Kali Settings and set USB Pass through.

Keep the card removed from the machine, restart the Kali Machine, insert the card and in the dialogue that comes up, connect the USB card to the machine, not Host.

Then you would need the Kali drivers for this particular card.

I have connected various USB cards to my own Kali machine this way. Kali V2020.4 , Kernel 5.8.0

Comment: Tryb nasłuchiwania (translated - Promiscuous mode) - is set to allow . check I posted new screenshot , changed language

Comment: Is this a Virtual Machine? It does not say above.  If not a VM, try setting the card for the "real" mode and not VM.

Comment: yes is it vm. you can see on screenshot oracle vm

Comment: I amended my answer to include pass through setup. You may wish to edit your question to indicate it is a VM and what the VM Host app is.